# finding closest recording speed in a list of numbers [python]

Tags: python, for-loop

I need to know how to loop through a list and find the closest speed to the speed limit. so pretty much Iterate through the list of speeds looking at the difference each time.

What I have so far:

```
def find_nearest_speed(recorded_speeds, speed_limit):
"""Finds the closest recorded speed when compared to the speed limit."""
closest = abs(speed_data[0] - speed_limit)
for current_element in speed_data:
    speed_difference = abs(current_element - speed_limit)
    if speed_difference < abs(closest - speed_limit):
        closest = current_element
        return closest

max_speed = 30 
speed_data = [24, 25, 27, 28, 31, 35]           
closest_speed = (find_nearest_speed(speed_data, max_speed))
print("The closest recorded speed was {} Km/h.".format(closest_speed))
```

What I get:

```
 The closest recorded speed was 24 Km/h.
```

What I should get:

```
 The closest recorded speed was 31 Km/h.
```

Comment: Why is it absolute value? Knowing what speed limits are, I would think it should be the closest to the speed limit without being under or over, but not just generally closest (over or under the limit)?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [min](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min):

```
max_speed = 30
speed_data = [24, 25, 27, 28, 31, 35]
closest_speed = min(speed_data, key=lambda x: abs(x - max_speed))
print("The closest recorded speed was {} Km/h.".format(closest_speed))
```

**Output**

```
The closest recorded speed was 31 Km/h.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you should have:

```
def find_nearest_speed(recorded_speeds, speed_limit):
"""Finds the closest recorded speed when compared to the speed limit."""
    closest = float('inf')
    for current_element in speed_data:
        speed_difference = abs(current_element - speed_limit)
        if speed_difference < abs(closest - speed_limit):
            closest = current_element
    return closest if len(recorded_speeds) > 0 else None
```

The only change is `closest = float('inf')` initially

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `return` statement "inside" the `if` statement, it will return as soon as the condition `speed_difference < abs(closest - speed_limit)` is `true`, which will be always satisfied with your code for the list first element.

So you need to remove the indentations before the `return` statement so it waits the end of the loop before returning the result.

Another note is that the statement `closest = abs(speed_data[0] - speed_limit)` is wrong because you're assigning the `closest` variable with the difference between the the list element and the `speed_limit`, but by seeing your function code you should rather assign it with the list element: `closest = speed_data[0]`.

```
def find_nearest_speed(recorded_speeds, speed_limit):
    """Finds the closest recorded speed when compared to the speed limit."""
    closest = speed_data[0] # Sets the closest as the list's first element
    for current_element in speed_data:
        speed_difference = abs(current_element - speed_limit)
        if speed_difference < abs(closest - speed_limit):
            closest = current_element
    return closest

max_speed = 30 
speed_data = [24, 25, 27, 28, 31, 35]           
closest_speed = (find_nearest_speed(speed_data, max_speed))
print("The closest recorded speed was {} Km/h.".format(closest_speed))
```